# Inverse function that takes connected set to non-connected set

Tags: general-topology

I've been struggling with providing examples of the following:

1) A continuous function $f$ and a connected set $E$ such that $f^{-1}(E)$ is not connected

2) A continuous function $g$ and a compact set $K$ such that $f^{-1}(K)$ is not compact

Comment: It suffices in both cases to take discrete spaces, and in 1) you can take finite discrete spaces.

Answer (score 9):

Let $f(x) = \sin x$, and let $E = [0,1]$.  Then $E$ is compact and connected, but $f^{-1}(E)$ is the disjoint union of infinitely many closed intervals, and is therefore neither compact nor connected.

Comment: He mentions inverse function, so sin is no example.

Comment: @peter The notation $f^{-1}(E)$ refers to the inverse image of a set $E$ under the function $f$.  The function $f$ itself does not need to be invertible.

Comment: what you say is true but doesnt touch the fact that the headline mentions an inverse function.

Answer (score 4):

Take any space $X$ which is not connected and not compact. For example, you could think of $\mathbf R - \{0\}$. Map this to a topological space consisting of one point. [What properties does such a space have?]

Answer (score 2):

For an example of an invertible function for the second part, map $[0,2\pi)$ to the unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$ via $t\rightarrow(\cos t, \sin t)$. $f$ is continuous, the unit circle $S$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is compact, but $f^{-1}(S)$ is not.

For the other example, take the space to be $[0,1)\cup[2,3]$ and the map to be
$$
f(x)=\cases{x,& $x\in[0,1)$\cr x-1,&$x\in [2,3]$ }
$$
Then $f$ is continuous, invertible, $[0,2]$ is connected, but $f^{-1}([0,2])$ is not.
(This actually furnishes an example for both parts.)